# Online Exe Builder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I generally use Visual Studio for creating Windows exe in C# .NET 2.0 / 3.5
But right now I dont have VS or any IDE / Compiler to build exe on my system and suppose I don't have admin rights to install them
Tell me please, how Can I build an exe online, something like coderun.com or codepad.org
But these sites are not helpful to me, as I need to build exe & download to my PC and use it.

I need some online solution to build EXE's online & run them on my PC.(Windows XP SP3)

Comment: Can you request admin rights or get an admin to install VS for you?

Comment: I do not have admin rights neither do i Have .NET framework installed or even if it is then it is Version 1.1 which comes with Windows XP SP2 or SP3 packs.Please suggest me a online site or service, payable or free to build exe on Windows ( particularly Windows XP SP3 ). Thanks

Comment: @user517780 if you want to download and run your .NET 2.0 exe as you said in your original question then you will need .NET Framework 2.0 installed to run it.

Comment: ya thats true.But I am also talking In case where I don't have .NET framework installed and I am required to build exe ?? What should I do in such case.. or else http://www.compilr.com/ is great !! Thanks Oded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some related sites, which *may help you ..*

http://www.ideone.com
http://www.compilers.net
http://www.chami.com/html-kit/devtools
http://www.icsharpcode.net
http://www.recursionsw.com
http://eli-project.sourceforge.net
http://www.openwatcom.com/index.php/Main_Page
http://ccache.samba.org/
http://codepad.org/
http://llvm.cs.uiuc.edu/DPJ/Home.html
http://www.coderun.com/
http://www.db4o.com/
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home
http://xacc.wordpress.com/

Comment: ideone is great for testing codes, I can run scripts :)

Answer (score 15):

The .NET Framework which ships with every modern version of Windows (and will probably be installed even on older versions) includes a command-line C# compiler called `csc.exe`.  You can build your exe with this.

Here are some instructions for using it:

- [MSDN: Command-line Building With csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

> The csc.exe executable is usually located in the `Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>` folder under the system directory.

Also, if you have the full version of .NET 4.0 (not client profile), you will probably have [msbuild.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) in the same place.  This is even easier to use, as you can simply pass it a Visual Studio solution file and it will build the whole solution for you, the same way Visual Studio does (apart from some special project types like installers).